# Selenium - button click downloads but doesn't redirect to linked page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, screen-scraping

I'm trying to click a "Download" button in a pop-up on a webpage. When I click it using Selenium (Chrome; Python), I know it's working because the file gets downloaded.

However, in addition to the javascript that downloads the file, the button has an href=# which should re-direct to the underlying page, (without the pop-up) once it's been clicked. When I click it in a live session using my mouse, the behavior is correct. But when using [button].click() in Selenium, the redirection is not happening - only the file download. Any tips or suggestions?

---

Edit: code snippets

Here is the button html:

```
<div class="buttons popup__buttons">
      <a href="#" class="button js-downloadLink">
            Download
      </a>
</div>
```

And my selenium code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button.js-downloadLink').click()
```

Comment: Can you provide html snippet of your button and a bit of context?

Comment: @AlexeyR. provided above in edited post

Comment: You're missing the leading `.` at the beginning of your classname. There should be `driver.find_element_by_class_name('.button.js-downloadLink').click()`. Please check if the fix will help somehow.

Comment: I tried adding the period but it's performing the same as before, there's no change and I still have the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

My suggest is to open chrome dev-tools and investigate what action is triggered by javascript. You may need to run a function with selenium that for some reason is not calling when using Selenium or check if the ids are loading properly.

if you want help share the website you want to scrape and we can have a look.

Every website is a new world! Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Still no idea with your snippet. Try the devtool. More precisely to the event listeners where its says click():

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I haven't been able to figure anything out using developer tools, but posted code snippets in my question, if it helps at all. I can't share the website because it's restricted access so you wouldn't be able to see the page I'm working on, unfortunately.